# Is there any Math assessment test I can take?

Tags: education

ever since I was a child I struggled with Maths. Just so you guys know I am 23-year-old system analyst. When I got into college, I realized how much Maths on a general sense is important to our lives on a daily basis. Therefore, I have been studying it almost daily for 3 years now.

I think I got a deep understanding of the basics: number sets (including complex and imaginary numbers), fractions, all types of functions, such as linear, quadratic, polynomials of higher degrees, power, logarithms, rational, irrational. I have just started learning calculus and I am mastering in derivatives. I know that Math is a huge science that people unfold every day... don't get me wrong here. 
Then, my question is: Is there a test (which is not that hard) that I can take in order to highlight my understanding in Math? I don't speak English as my first language and I remember that when I was learning it, there were several tests to assess my English level, such as TOEFL, IELTS, Cambridge, etc. Is there something similar? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the USA, high school students take a test called the Scholastic Aptitude Test (SAT), which tests both language and math skills. I think there are four sections to the test, two on language and two on math. (It's been a long time since I took the test.)  You can find free practice tests online that you can download and take for free.  You can take just the two math sections if you aren't interested in the other parts.

I'm not sure if the free SAT practice tests are at the level you want, but they are free, so you have nothing to lose by trying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am Brazilian, therefore I don't think I could take the official SAT, do you think it would be nice if I put the practice tests outcome on my résumé? My intention is to ensure people that I know Maths. I have been studying at a Math school and I think I will get my certificate soon, but I also would like to have some sort of exam certification

Comment: @MatheusMinguini  I doubt that it would be useful to put the results on your resume.  You take the practice test at your leisure, and maybe even grade it yourself, unlike the official tests which are administered in a controlled environment with time constraints, so I don't think the results would impress anyone.

Comment: Thank you... I am gonna try out the SAT at my leisure, then! Thanks again for your time as well as your response